# UIView layoutSubviews delegation

Tags: ios, uiview, delegation

I find myself wanting support for delegating the responsibility of layoutSubviews for a UIView. This to avoid having to make a specific subclass just to implement the layoutSubviews method. I'm suspecting the reason I found my self wanting this alternative might be because I've missed some fundamental UIKit design considerations, or? Or should I just go ahead and make my own UIView subclass with support for this type of layout delegation?

Comment: See BNRBlockView for something similar with by using blocks instead of delegates: http://www.informit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=Ask-Big-Nerd-Ranch-Blocks-in-Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to create a subclass whenever you need a custom layout, there is no way to delegate.  It's also the only sane way to do it- if you're containing a set of views in a superview, that view should control its subview layout for maintainability.

You also don't have to do view layout in layoutSubviews- you can simply create the layout when you create the superview, and assign positions and sizes at that point, if you don't need something reusable.